# Insert GET-parameter into static files with Nginx

Tags: testing, nginx, jsonp

I'm testing some client side magic with Nginx forward proxy and a few rewrites, and it works great. Now I want to also mock up JSONP responses. It requires replacing a callback name placeholder in a static JSONP file with a query parameter.

To illustrate, the `jsonp.js` file:

```
<CALLBACK>({ "json": [] })
```

The URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/jsonp.js?callback=myCustomCallback
```

I want to serve the file modified like that:

```
myCustomCallback({ "json": [] })
```

Is it possible with Nginx? Preferably, using the SSI module and not Perl or Lua.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [http_sub_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html)

Something like this may work:

```
sub_filter '<CALLBACK>' $arg_callback;
```